# error related to static linking of glibcxx and glibc

Tags: g++

I am am trying to cross-compile an x86 program for alpha using g++. For that, I tried both "-static-libgcc" and "--static" options when linking the object file with libraries to generate the binaries. The cross compilation was successful, however I got the following errors when I ran the binaries on alpha machine:

./word_count: /lib/libc.so.6.1: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by ./word_count)
./word_count: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.10' not found (required by ./word_

These errors shouldn't happen, since I am using static linking! So, I cannot figure out why I am getting these errors! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link against both, standard C and C++ libraries. ([source](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/06/static-libstdc/))

Comment: I just did it, but the problem still remains! Any idea?

Comment: He describes two ways to fix it. Which one did you try?

Comment: I used commands similar to these to direct the cross compiler to use those libraries rather than looking for shared objects:              ln -s `g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.a`

g++ -static-libgcc -L. -o example example.cpp

Comment: Did you try the compiler flag `-static-libstdc++`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it is not supported by the cross compiler that I am using, since it has a gcc version 4.3.

Comment: @Moonwild Sorry, I'm stumped. I never had such a problem.